# replacing part of a string by position in c#

Tags: c#, string, string-matching

I have a string: ===FILE CONTENT==\r\n@something here... }\r\n\r\n@something here 2... }\t\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n@something here 3... }\r@something here 4...} \n

using c#, I want get all strings inside this string that starts with '@' and ends with '}', but I having a problem with getting the position of '@' and '}' since newline and tabs are not fix. thank you in advance

here is the sample output:

```
new string 1 = "@something here... }";
 new string 2 = "@something here 2... }";
 new string 3="@something here 3... }";
 new string 4="@something here 4...}";
```

Comment: use IndexOf and LastIndexOf and then use substring

Answer (score 1):

See code below:

```
string[] getSubstrings(string str)
{
    return str.Split('@')
        .Select(s => "@" + s.Substring(0, 1 + s.IndexOf('}')))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: you may have missed a closing parenthesis at the end of the .Select. Great answer. Succinct. +1

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler, thanks, I am getting too reliant on visual studio to highlight those for me, hard to keep count of open parenthesis when typing in browser :)

Comment: I did try this one and it works on me Thank you guys I really appreciate this. I have another concern related to this. 
First, how to bypass string with ';@' example ";@something here 3... }". should I add execption before return str.Split('@')?
Second. lets say if I have character '}' or @ is inside '@ }' format it should be treated as part of my string not as terminator.

sample output string: @BOOK_SERVIE ;DATE 01/2015\r\n{\r\n BOOK CONTENT ;  chapter1    page2 ;' C¢}>' \r\n chapter2 b8 , ;' @C¢}8'}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"@[^}]*}");
var listOfMatches = new List<string>();
for (var match = regex.Match(inputString); match.Success; match = match.NextMatch())
{
    listOfMatches.Add(match.Value);
}
```